# Forcing inline-block elements to scroll horizontally while still allowing vertical scroll

Tags: html, css

> Note: the included CSS has my attempts at making the horizontal scroll
> in the **article** element removed, I've tried a few things, to no
> avail!

I've come across as few articles similar to the issue I'm having but not quite addressing the exact thing I'm missing, unless I'm not paying enough attention.

I have a series of inline elements within inline-block elements, and I want to allow vertical overflow of individual **section** elements to remain visible, while forcing them to scroll horizontally within their container. The idea is to have 1-3 (depending on media query) sets of lyrics appear on screen, and scroll horizontally using JS scroll locations.

The issue I'm coming across, however, is that the overflow of the **sections** always goes vertically, with 3 spans on the line below.

```css
    div.music {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: 7px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
        height: calc(100% - 262px);
        background: linear-gradient(#000, #485666);
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
    article.lyrics {
        width: 54%;
        display: inline-block;
        padding:0;
        padding-top: 15px;
        height: calc(100% - 15px);
        font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    }
    
    section.lyrcon {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
        text-align: left;
        width: 33%;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

```html
        <div class="music">
        <span class="previous"><a href="#"><div class="pre"></div></a></span>
            <article class="lyrics">
                <section class="lyrcon">
                    Lyrics
                </section>
        
                <section class="lyrcon">
                    Lyrics
                </section>
                
                <section class="lyrcon">
                    Lyrics
                </section>
                            
                <section class="lyrcon">
                    Lyrics
                </section>
                
                <section class="lyrcon">
                    Lyrics
                </section>
                
                <section class="lyrcon">
                    Lyrics
                </section>
            </article>
        <span class="next"><a href="#"><div class="nex"></div></a></span>
    </div>
```

I'm willing to admit that I may be going about this in completely the wrong way, but it's working for me layout wise (screenshot of layout below), so any advice about how to solve the issue, or an alternate approach would be most appreciated.

[image: 1]

Comment: `section.lyrcon {display:inline-block;}` and remove `float`, `article.lyrics {white-space:nowrap; overflow-x:scroll;}`

Comment: This... is perfect, actually! That's solved everything, thank you

Answer (score 0):

add to `article.lyrics` this

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
overflow-x: auto;
```

add to `article.lyrcon` this

```
flex-shrink: 0;
```

```css
div.music {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: 7px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
        height: calc(100% - 262px);
        background: linear-gradient(#000, #485666);
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
    article.lyrics {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        overflow-x: auto;
        padding:0;
        padding-top: 15px;
        height: calc(100% - 15px);
        font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    }
    
    section.lyrcon {
        flex-shrink: 0;
        float: left;
        text-align: left;
        width: 33%;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

```html
      <div class="music">
        <span class="previous"><a href="#"><div class="pre"></div></a></span>
            <article class="lyrics">
                <section class="lyrcon">
                    Lyrics
                </section>
        
                <section class="lyrcon">
                    Lyrics
                </section>
                
                <section class="lyrcon">
                    Lyrics
                </section>
                            
                <section class="lyrcon">
                    Lyrics
                </section>
                
                <section class="lyrcon">
                    Lyrics
                </section>
                
                <section class="lyrcon">
                    Lyrics
                </section>
            </article>
        <span class="next"><a href="#"><div class="nex"></div></a></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ah, genius! That's certainly solved the horizontal scrolling issue, thank you! Changing the "display" to flex, caused some layout issues, so I changed it to "inline-flex" which fixed most of it, however there's now a large margin above the article.lyrics.

I'm sure I'll figure it out with some poking about, but any ideas of the top of your head that I haven't considered?